# Inherited class object not showing base class method

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'd like to put in a base class a method in order not to repeat it in the inherited classes. There are interfaces for the base class and the inherited classes. Once I create a inherited class object I cannot use the base class method that I want to use. ¿What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    string GetError(string LogNumber);
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Repository()
    {
    }

    public string GetError(string LogNumber)
    {
        return "The error is " + LogNumber;
    }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    // READ
    List<Customer> ReadAll();

}

public class CustomerRepository : Repository, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository() : base()
    {
    }


    public List<Customer> ReadAll()
    {
        return fooFunction();
    }
}

CustomerRepository myRepository = new CustomerRepository()
myRepository.
```

Comment: What base class method do you want to use? How do you know you can't use it? What error does it show when you try?

Comment: Your code looks OK so far but you seemed to have stopped half-way through a line. Can you add the rest of the example please?

Comment: I've stopped where GetError() method should be shown. No idea why intellisense is not showing it available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code working fine. Please check below solution

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CustomerRepository myRepository = new CustomerRepository();
            myRepository.GetError("string error");

        }
        public interface IRepository
        {
            string GetError(string LogNumber);
        }

        public class Repository : IRepository
        {
            public Repository()
            {
            }

            public string GetError(string LogNumber)
            {
                return "The error is " + LogNumber;
            }
        }

        public interface ICustomerRepository
        {
            // READ
            List<Customer> ReadAll();

        }

        public class CustomerRepository : Repository, ICustomerRepository
        {
            public CustomerRepository() : base()
            {
            }


            public List<Customer> ReadAll()
            {
                List<Customer> list;
                return list = new List<Customer>();
            }
        }

        public class Customer
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put these statements outside the class? If yes, you should put them inside a method or preferably inside a main method.
Also, there is a semicolon missing at the end of the object initialization.

"CustomerRepository myRepository = new CustomerRepository()***;***

myRepository."

Try correcting, you will be able to access the method from your base class.